# Renaming a:after, a:hover, a

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have been working on my site an i ran into a problem where a:hover overrides two different things. My top tabs (Download, testtab, testtab) on my website used to change color when you hover over them, but once i added one of my image button a:hover commands it stopped working because they both have the same name. The image button i am talking about is at the bottom, it doesn't appear on the jsfiddle but you should get the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/d6h1jpbj/

So this is the first thing i added which basically told my tabs to change color when i hovered over them.

```
.boxhead a {    

    color: #afaeae;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a { 
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;

    }
a:hover {

    color: #7d7d7d;
}
```

This is the second thing i later added with my image button hover effect. 
For some reason since    they have the same name the tabs stoped working. I added a jsfiddle of my site to show you what i    mean.

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 238px;
  height: 238px;
}
.image a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image a:after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(91, 200, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.image a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I have tried putting the css into two different divs and that didn't seem to work, so i am a bit stuck atm.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<body>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="boxhead">
            <h2>
                <a href="myLink" style="margin-left:180px; float: left; width: 90px; margin-top: -40px; z- index: 1;"><span id="otherPage">Downloads</span></a>
            </h2>
            <h2>
                <a href="myLink" style="margin-left: 340px; float: left; width: 90px; margin-top: -40px; z-index: 1;"><span id="otherPage1">Testtab</span></a>
            </h2>
            <h2>
                <a href="myLink" style="margin-left: 480px; float: left; width: 90px; margin-top: -40px; z-   index: 1;"><span id="otherPage2">Testtab</div> </span></a>
            </h2>
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mountain View" style=" float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-top:     -50px; z-index: 1;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line25"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
        <div class="line4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrappers">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="#"> <img src="img/teslalogo.jpg" alt="Clickable" /> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is the follow, never add A or A.Hover just use the follow code and it will work

```
.boxhead 
{    
color: #afaeae;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}

.boxhead:hover 
{
color: #7d7d7d;
}
```

Comment: The A a link a hover a visited is a very old way to create website links when css does not existed like today and you needed to do a hard job because the only browser we had was internet explorer mostly, now with chrome and mozilla things changed and the world too

Comment: Oh sorry forgot the :

    .boxhead:hover

Answer (score 1):

You can manage different style for your anchor tag by separating the anchors via class name.

For e.g. lets assume your HTML looks like

```
<a class='google' href='www.google.com'>Google</a>
<a class='facebook' href='www.facebook.com'>Facebook</a>
```

Then you need to write css like this

```
a.google {
    color: red;
}

a.google:hover {
    color: green;
}


a.facebook {
    color: blue;
}

a.facebook:hover {
    color: red;
}
```